# Infering correct string literal in method

Tags: typescript

I need help convincing Typescript to infer string literal which was put it by user, instead of using one with all possible values.

Take a look at this example ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20Supported%20methods.%0D%0Atype%20Methods%20%3D%20%22GET%22%20%7C%20%22PUT%22%20%2F*%20and%20etc.%20*%2F%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Event%20interface%20for%20each%20method.%0D%0Ainterface%20Events%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20%5Bany%2C%20any%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Event%20objects%20assigned%20to%20methods.%0D%0Atype%20MethodicalEvents%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%20in%20Methods%5D%3A%20Events%20%7C%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Extract%20string%20keys%20only.%0D%0Atype%20EventKeys%3CE%20extends%20Events%3E%20%3D%20Extract%3Ckeyof%20E%2C%20string%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Extract%20all%20event%20keys%20from%20%60MethodicalEvents%20-%3E%20Events%60.%0D%0Atype%20AllEvents%3CO%20extends%20MethodicalEvents%2C%20M%20extends%20Methods%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20O%5BM%5D%20extends%20object%20%3F%20EventKeys%3CO%5BM%5D%3E%20%3A%20never%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Extract%20send%20value%20(first%20array%20value%20in%20%60Events%60%20interface).%0D%0Atype%20ExtractSendValue%3CO%20extends%20MethodicalEvents%2C%20M%20extends%20Methods%2C%20E%20extends%20AllEvents%3CO%2C%20M%3E%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20O%5BM%5D%20extends%20object%20%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20O%5BM%5D%5BE%5D%20extends%20%5Bany%2C%20any%5D%20%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20O%5BM%5D%5BE%5D%5B0%5D%20%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20never%20%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20never%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Interface%20implementing%20stuff%20from%20above.%0D%0Ainterface%20Foo%20extends%20MethodicalEvents%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PUT%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%221%22%3A%20%5B123%2C%20void%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%222%22%3A%20%5Bstring%2C%20void%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%223%22%3A%20%5Bboolean%2C%20void%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Class%20for%20making%20requests%20via%20%60Foo%60%20interface.%0D%0Aclass%20Bar%3CO%20extends%20MethodicalEvents%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20request%3CM%20extends%20Methods%2C%20E%20extends%20AllEvents%3CO%2C%20M%3E%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20method%3A%20M%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event%3A%20E%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20ExtractSendValue%3CO%2C%20M%2C%20E%3E%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Do%20stuff...%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20bar%20%3D%20new%20Bar%3CFoo%3E()%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%60true%60%20should%20not%20be%20allowed.%0D%0Abar.request(%22PUT%22%2C%20%221%22%2C%20true%20%2F*type%3A%20%60string%20%7C%20boolean%20%7C%20123%60*%2F)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20type%20is%20%60123%60%2C%20as%20expected%0D%0Atype%20ExpectedType%20%3D%20ExtractSendValue%3CFoo%2C%20%22PUT%22%2C%20%221%22%3E%3B%0D%0A)):

```
// Supported methods.
type Methods = "GET" | "PUT" /* and etc. */;

// Event interface for each method.
interface Events {
    [key: string]: [any, any];
}

// Event objects assigned to methods.
type MethodicalEvents = {
    [key in Methods]: Events | undefined;
};

// Extract string keys only.
type EventKeys<E extends Events> = Extract<keyof E, string>;

// Extract all event keys from `MethodicalEvents -> Events`.
type AllEvents<O extends MethodicalEvents, M extends Methods> =
    O[M] extends object ? EventKeys<O[M]> : never;

// Extract send value (first array value in `Events` interface).
type ExtractSendValue<O extends MethodicalEvents, M extends Methods, E extends AllEvents<O, M>> =
    O[M] extends object ?
    O[M][E] extends [any, any] ?
    O[M][E][0] :
    never :
    never;

// Interface implementing stuff from above.
interface Foo extends MethodicalEvents {
    PUT: {
        "1": [123, void];
        "2": [string, void];
        "3": [boolean, void];
    };
}

// Class for making requests via `Foo` interface.
class Bar<O extends MethodicalEvents> {
    public request<M extends Methods, E extends AllEvents<O, M>>(
        method: M,
        event: E,
        data: ExtractSendValue<O, M, E>,
    ) {
        // Do stuff...
    }
}

const bar = new Bar<Foo>();
// `true` should not be allowed.
bar.request("PUT", "1", true /*type: `string | boolean | 123`*/);

// type is `123`, as expected
type ExpectedType = ExtractSendValue<Foo, "PUT", "1">;
```

Second argument of `bar.request` has type of `"1" | "2" | "3"` whereas I would like it to have `"1"` as a type.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I believe this is a bug, you could file it on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks, your solution indeed works and I will open an issue on Github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you for sure why the inference does not work as you expect it to, I would expect it to. `AllEvents<O, M>` should work out to a constraint of `"1"|"2"|"3"`, which should in turn let the compiler infer for `E` the literal type `"1"`. It instead infers `"1"|"2"|"3"`.

From my testing the issue is with the use of `Extract` in `Extract<keyof E, string>;` If we remove this the inference works as expected (although this might be required for your use-case).

A workaround for the bug is reordering the conditionals in `AllEvent`. This seems to work:

```
// Supported methods.
type Methods = "GET" | "PUT" /* and etc. */;

// Event interface for each method.
interface Events {
    [key: string]: [any, any];
}

// Event objects assigned to methods.
type MethodicalEvents = {
    [key in Methods]: Events | undefined;
};

// Extract all event keys from `MethodicalEvents -> Events`.
type AllEvents<O extends MethodicalEvents, M extends Methods> = Extract<O[M] extends object ? keyof O[M] : never, string>

// Extract send value (first array value in `Events` interface).
type ExtractSendValue<O extends MethodicalEvents, M extends Methods, E extends AllEvents<O, M>> =
    O[M] extends object ?
    O[M][E] extends [any, any] ?
    O[M][E][0] :
    never :
    never;

// Interface implementing stuff from above.
interface Foo extends MethodicalEvents {
    PUT: {
        "1": [123, void];
        "2": [string, void];
        "3": [boolean, void];
    };
}

// Class for making requests via `Foo` interface.
class Bar<O extends MethodicalEvents> {
    public request<M extends Methods, E extends AllEvents<O, M>>(
        method: M,
        event: E,
        data: ExtractSendValue<O, M, E >,
    ) {
        // Do stuff...
    }
}

const bar = new Bar<Foo>();
// `true` is not allowed
bar.request("PUT", "1", true /*type: `string | boolean | 123`*/);

// type is `123`, as expected
type ExpectedType = ExtractSendValue<Foo, "PUT", "1">;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20Supported%20methods.%0D%0Atype%20Methods%20%3D%20%22GET%22%20%7C%20%22PUT%22%20%2F*%20and%20etc.%20*%2F%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Event%20interface%20for%20each%20method.%0D%0Ainterface%20Events%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20%5Bany%2C%20any%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Event%20objects%20assigned%20to%20methods.%0D%0Atype%20MethodicalEvents%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%20in%20Methods%5D%3A%20Events%20%7C%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Extract%20all%20event%20keys%20from%20%60MethodicalEvents%20-%3E%20Events%60.%0D%0Atype%20AllEvents%3CO%20extends%20MethodicalEvents%2C%20M%20extends%20Methods%3E%20%3D%20Extract%3CO%5BM%5D%20extends%20object%20%3F%20keyof%20O%5BM%5D%20%3A%20never%2C%20string%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Extract%20send%20value%20(first%20array%20value%20in%20%60Events%60%20interface).%0D%0Atype%20ExtractSendValue%3CO%20extends%20MethodicalEvents%2C%20M%20extends%20Methods%2C%20E%20extends%20AllEvents%3CO%2C%20M%3E%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20O%5BM%5D%20extends%20object%20%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20O%5BM%5D%5BE%5D%20extends%20%5Bany%2C%20any%5D%20%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20O%5BM%5D%5BE%5D%5B0%5D%20%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20never%20%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20never%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Interface%20implementing%20stuff%20from%20above.%0D%0Ainterface%20Foo%20extends%20MethodicalEvents%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PUT%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%221%22%3A%20%5B123%2C%20void%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%222%22%3A%20%5Bstring%2C%20void%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%223%22%3A%20%5Bboolean%2C%20void%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Class%20for%20making%20requests%20via%20%60Foo%60%20interface.%0D%0Aclass%20Bar%3CO%20extends%20MethodicalEvents%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20request%3CM%20extends%20Methods%2C%20E%20extends%20AllEvents%3CO%2C%20M%3E%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20method%3A%20M%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event%3A%20E%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20ExtractSendValue%3CO%2C%20M%2C%20E%20%3E%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Do%20stuff...%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20bar%20%3D%20new%20Bar%3CFoo%3E()%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%60true%60%20is%20not%20allowed%0D%0Abar.request(%22PUT%22%2C%20%221%22%2C%20true%20%2F*type%3A%20%60string%20%7C%20boolean%20%7C%20123%60*%2F)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20type%20is%20%60123%60%2C%20as%20expected%0D%0Atype%20ExpectedType%20%3D%20ExtractSendValue%3CFoo%2C%20%22PUT%22%2C%20%221%22%3E%3B%0D%0A)